# Generate random integers between 1 and 1000

Tags: python-3.x

I have attached my code. I want the output to be :

```
[675, 556, 329]
[554, 469, 784, 133]
[896, 414, 662, 826, 501]
```

However the output I get is simply:

```
[321]
[32]
[342]
```

How can I show three items in the list instead of just one?

My code is:

```
import random
# Create your function here

def random_number_generator(l):
    number = []
    length = len(number)
    for length in range(0, l):
        number.append(random.randrange(0,1000))
        return number

print(random_number_generator(3)) 
print(random_number_generator(4))
print(random_number_generator(5))
```

Comment: de-dent `return number`. Also, note that the line `length = len(number)` doesn't do anything

Comment: Your `return` statement is within the `for` loop, so it is returning after a single iteration.  De-indent it one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def random_number_generator(l):
    number = []
    for length in range(0, l):
        number.append(random.randrange(0,1000))
    return number
```

Comment: You should explain what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. While deindenting the return worked, I also tried another loop which worked well:

```
import random
# Create your function here

def random_number_generator(l):
    number = []
    while len(number) < l:
        number.append(random.randrange(0,1000))
        continue
    return number

print(random_number_generator(3)) 
print(random_number_generator(4))
print(random_number_generator(5))
```